# C# condition on using assembly

Tags: c#, assembly, conditional-statements

I saw a few post on this but non of them worked for me.
I have a project using a third party dll. There are several versions of the dll but I am only using 2. *ThirdParty8.dll* and *ThirdParty9.dll*

This project will be deployed on different clients using one of the two versions of the dll. 
Due to licensing issues I cannot have the latest version installed on everyone. But the code is created for version 8 and will work with no changes on ThirdParty9.dll except on the using statement.
One will be

```
using ThirdParty8;
```

and the other one

```
using ThirdParty9;
```

Classes have the same name.

Is there any way to select the one to be used on a condition? example

```
if (configfile.version = 8)
    using ThirdParty8;
else
    using ThirdParty9;
```

Thanks

Gianfranco

Comment: I don't fell I understand your problem completely, but if you have a same name classes with different dll's, you should use their full names like `ThirdParty8.ClassName` and `ThirdParty9.ClassName`

Comment: Why not use comilation arguments

Comment: if you are `using` these assemblies in source, doesn't that mean you have imported references to both DLLs in your solution? I am not sure you can load the compiled code on your target systems which only have one DLL present - even if the code is designed such that that the library-specific classes are never used. You should look into the `Assembly.LoadFrom` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) method and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like

```
#if VERSION8
using ThirdParty8
#else
using ThirdParty9
#endif
```

If it's correct, maybe you can define a Conditional like VERSION8, and compile with or without it.

Comment: if the OP has the desire to have 'one version' of the application to distribute, this technique could still be used - with some clever project definitions, build targets, and a well written installer

Comment: This would be the way of doing it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with classes in namespaces. For example:

```
if (configfile.version == 8)
   doSomething8(ThirdParty8.Car);
else
   doSomething9(ThirdParty9.Car);

void doSomething8(ThirdParty8.Car car)
{
   //do you get it?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "Classes have the same name", try this:

```
  string strName = this.GetType().Name;

  if (strName == ThirdParty8.ClassName)
  { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fudge this, by doing something with a C# directive

```
#if DEF_USE_TP8
using ThirdParty8;
#endif
```

which is a C style solution to the problem, and then compiling two separate DLL's from the same source code, each compiled using the appropriate compiler directive, but this is not a C# style solution.

My preference would be to go back to the library providers and question why they have a namespace change when the underlying object interfaces have not changed, explaining that this in effect breaks all their customers code.

The answer to this question will probably help you understand why and what you need to do to handle this now, and into the future.  (i.e are there interface differences? are they going to do this on the next release too? etc...)